# Set routing table to use vpn connection first (c#)

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to setup vpn connection. my pbk file that located in `"C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk"` and there is an VPN entry in it -

```
RasEntry.CreateVpnEntry(connectionName, serverAddress, RasVpnStrategy.Default, RasDevice.GetDeviceByName("(PPTP)", RasDeviceType.Vpn), false);
```

How to change route table to use this connection for all traffic?